# Não consigo editar altura de um banner slider em class="slider-section"

Tags: html, css, slider

Estou com um site para editar e não consigo alterar a altura do slider inicial, pois não faz referência direta no `CSS`, ou ao menos não consigo encontrar. Vejam o trecho do código para entender melhor:

```
<div class="slider-section">
    <div class="tp-banner-container">
        <div class="tp-banner">
            <ul>
                <li data-transition="fade" data-slotamount="1" data-masterspeed="500" data-thumb="upload/banner-2.png"  data-saveperformance="off"  data-title="Garden">
                    <img src="upload/banner-2.png"  alt="halfslide1"  data-bgposition="center top" data-bgfit="cover" data-bgrepeat="no-repeat">
                    <div class="tp-caption slider_layer_02 text-center lft tp-resizeme"
                        data-x="center"
                        data-y="230"
                        data-speed="1000"
                        data-start="800"
                        data-easing="Power3.easeInOut"
                        data-splitin="none"
                        data-splitout="none"
                        data-elementdelay="0.1"
                        data-endelementdelay="0.1"
                        data-endspeed="1000"
                        style="z-index: 9; max-width: auto; max-height: 70%; white-space: nowrap; ">Espaço ideal para festas infantis
                    </div>
                    <div class="tp-caption slider_layer_01 text-center lft tp-resizeme"
                        data-x="center"
                        data-y="295"
                        data-speed="1000"
                        data-start="1200"
                        data-easing="Power3.easeInOut"
                        data-splitin="none"
                        data-splitout="none"
                        data-elementdelay="0.1"
                        data-endelementdelay="0.1"
                        data-endspeed="1000"
                        style="z-index: 9; max-width: auto; max-height: 70%; white-space: nowrap;">Agende já uma data!
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Bom então vamos la. Na sua div slide, ela está com o estilo de max-height: 70%;

esses 70% quer dizer que ele vai ter altura de no máximo 70% de sua tag pai, que no caso é a li Está li está definida alguma altura? A pai da li é a ul, tem alguma altura definida para ela também? Lembrando que se você for trabalhar apenas com % para um layout responsivo, você precisa definir a altura desde o inicio do projeto.

```
html,body{
   height: 100%;
}
```

dessa forma quando você coloca max-hegiht: 70% o projeto terá noção do que são esses 70%. Da uma olhada ai e me avisa.

Comment: tens razão, mas mesmo assim não rsolveu. Segue a div completa:

Comment: Na verdade ele está fechando sim Bruno, só que a estrutura do código na questão estava sendo exibida incorretamente. Editei e ajustei já.